# Dados do banco vem incompleto

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho dois dados no banco, mas fazendo o select somente 1 aparece, pq?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$opcao = $_GET['opcao'];

switch ($opcao) {
    case 'pegaCategoria':

    $pegaCategoria=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoriaComum");
    $pegaCategoria->execute();

    $return = array();

    while ($linhaCateAdmin=$pegaCategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $idcategoriaComum = $linhaCateAdmin['idcategoriaComum'];
        $categoriaComum = $linhaCateAdmin['categoriaComum'];

        $return = [
            "idcategoriaComum" => $idcategoriaComum,
            "categoriaComum" => $categoriaComum
        ];

    }

    echo json_encode($return);

    break;
?>
```

E pela imagem abaixo, vocês podem ver que tenho dois dados na tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no console, é exibido 1 apenas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `$return` está sendo reatribuido toda hora, vc precisa adicionar uma novo item no array. `$return[] = ['chave' => valor]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim estás a reescrever o valor e acabas só com os ultimos retornados no ultimo loop, faz isto:

```
...
$return = array();
while ($linhaCateAdmin=$pegaCategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $return[] = [
            "idcategoriaComum" => $linhaCateAdmin['idcategoriaComum'],
            "categoriaComum" => $linhaCateAdmin['categoriaComum']
        ];

}
echo json_encode($return);
break;
...
```

Comment: Valeu Miguel...

Comment: De nada @GustavoSevero